# Python azure-servicebus throws circular import error for ServiceBusClient and ServiceBusMessage

Tags: python, azure, importerror, servicebus

After installing azure servicebus from pypl( azure-servicebus 7.3.4 ) using pip, i am trying those provided sample code from https://pypi.org/project/azure-servicebus/.

It gives error:
from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusClient
ImportError: cannot import name 'ServiceBusClient' from partially initialized module 'azure.servicebus' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\python\lib\site-packages\azure\servicebus_*init*_.py)

I am using windows10.

other azure services like FaceAPI and CustomVision libraries are working fine.
Just this ServiceBus is throwing error.

I am new to azure in python. Any kind help of help is highly appreciable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you don’t have any of your working `.py` file named  like `ServiceBusClient.py` or `ServiceBusMessage.py` or `azure_servicebus.py` which can conflict with Python/ServiceBus package installed files.

If you are using `Python 3.8.9`, you can try installing the lower version of `azure-servicbus` as answered by [Frank Gong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67229001/15969115)

```
pip install azure-servicebus==7.0.0
```

You can refer to [ImportError: cannot import name '...' from partially initialized module '...' (most likely due to a circular import)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64807163/importerror-cannot-import-name-from-partially-initialized-module-m), [Circular Import Error while importing create_engine in Sqlalchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60587325/circular-import-error-while-importing-create-engine-in-sqlalchemy?rq=1),  and  [ImportError: cannot import name 'ServiceBusClient' from 'azure.servicebus'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67218513/importerror-cannot-import-name-servicebusclient-from-azure-servicebus)

You can refer to the available [Azure Service Bus libraries for Python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/servicebus?view=azure-python)

Comment: It worked like charm!! Thank you. I installed python3.6 and then azure-servicebus. Its working fine.